# Element xx is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I am getting this error in one of my pages: **Element 9 is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression**.
I even tried to dump that specific structure and result is same.

```
<cfdump var="#(request.session.cust.dra_info[versionid].bm[gradecd]#">
```

[image: Error]

The **[VerionID]** is the reason i am getting this error. Versionid might be coming as 9 which doesnt exists. This versionid and gradecd is coming from a query.
Here is the dump of that query:
[image: Query]

The dump of the structure gives me below result:

```
<cfdump var="#request.session.cust.dra_info#">
```

[image]

Any help/suggestion how should i handle this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means "You are passing a value (in your case 9) which is not present in the structure". This value might refer to **versionId** or **gradecd**.
 
You need pass only those values which are available in the structure.  I can not say how to do that without looking at code.

**EDIT**
You can do like this

```
<cfif structKeyExists(request.session.cust.dra_info,"#versionId#")>
    <cfdump var="#(request.session.cust.dra_info[versionid].bm[gradecd]#"><cfabort>
<cfelse>    
    <cfdump var="not ok- error handling code"><cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Comment: you are correct Tushar - versionid is the cause. The versionid(which is cmng from a query) has value 9. I am not sure what was developers idea, but i am new to this application. So even i cant tell you why such a case here. But can we not handle this error by putting any condition?

Comment: If you look at the dump of that structure above, the 'dra_info' have only two values 83 and 86. Hence when it is passing values as 9, it is dying. When i just hard coded a value as [83] it worked fine - <cfdump var="#request.session.cust.dra_info[83]#">